# This was half a Rudy - Klaus

Tags: the-umbrella-academy

In the season 3 finale of the Umbrella Academy Kalus and Luther are fighting in the afterworld until Klaus agrees to help with saving the family. Klaus then rates Luther's speech as

> On a scale of one to Braveheart this was half a Rudy.

What's a Rudy?

Comment: There was a 1993 sportsball movie called *Rudy*...

Comment: Possibly this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pr1yE1ox8aY

Comment: That scene seems a pretty good fit